# Making the #include square

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write a makefile using CC on Solaris 10. [Only the first bit of that really matters, I think].  I have the following rule for foo.o:

```
foo.o: foo.cc common_dependencies.h
    CC -c foo.cc -I../../common
```

Unfortunately, common_dependencies.h includes all sorts of idiosyncratic trash, in directories not named '.' or '../../common' .  Is this just going to have to be a brute force makefile where I ferret out all of the dependency paths?  All of the dependencies are somewhere under '../..', but sometimes 1-level down and sometimes 2-levels down.

-Thanks Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, if header files are shared amongst source files in multiple directories, they are kept in an `include/` tree under the project root, and then you use something like `-I$(TOPDIR)/include` to add the include tree to the include path and let your source files pull in `include/foo/bar.h` like so:

```
#include "foo/bar.h"
```

Comment: This may be typical, but it doesn't hold in the case David describes.

Comment: Actually, it is OK.  We are, uhh, 'reusing' some legacy stuff which was horribly disorganized.  We haven't baselined it, though, so I took the liberty to make a local copy [it's not very big when it is all said and done] and reorganize it.  So, I'm just going to do a little more housework.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is pretty mean in general. There are plenty of conventions for project organization plus tools to help (`autoconf` and similar), but if the author hasn't taken advantage of those things you're going to have to hunt everything down and install the `-I`s yourself.

You could use `gcc -M` or `makedepends` or one of the many similar tools to get a list of the directories that are needed. Presumably you could even script the extraction.

Comment: I used CC -xM1, which is the idiomatic usage, but it dumps the cant-finds to STDERR (i.e. CC -xM1 foo.cc > dependencies) gets all the includes it can find, and doesn't get any of the things that can't be found. I could python it it up, which would be the most natural for me, but it might take an hour, and I just wanted to get a community check before I took off on a tangent.

Comment: Thanks, though, I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not a good idea to specify a path in an #include directive; it makes the header -- and anything that depends on it -- dependent on a particular directory structure. It's worth finding out whether you're allowed to clean up common_dependencies.h itself.

If the paths in common_dependencies.h are correct, then your Makefile will work as is (although I'd recommend using an absolute path, not "../.."), and you can use somthing like [Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html) to handle the dependencies for you.

If the paths in common_dependencies.h are not correct, then yes, you'll have to find every file that it #includes, *and knowing where they are won't be enough*. If it #includes a file with a false path, the compilation will crash even if the compiler has -Ithe_correct_path, so you'll have to either fix common_dependencies.h or modify the directory structure (by moving, copying or linking to the files).

Comment: This lump of code started life as a blob in a single directory, without so much as a whiff of unit testing, with revision histories that are not current [last change '94, except for //B.Lah's debug statement 12/01, for example].  Makes finding dependencies easy, they are all part of the lump, but it confounds most quality practices.  I'm hoping to do make some organizational changes to affect the latter. [And this may include refactoring common_dependencies.h, because it is seriously hosed].  Thanks, advice taken and recommendation recognized.